# search: different custom fields across multiple channels

Tags: channel, search

I have a couple channels with different custom fields.
I would like to combine the entries of multiple channels using the search: parameter, however, I can't specify to which channel the search: parameter applies.

Something equivalent to this:

```
{exp:channel:entries
    channel='articles|videos|news'

    search:[channel:articles]:article_videos="not IS_EMPTY"
    search:[channel:videos]:video_url="not IS_EMPTY"
    search:[channel:news]:news_video="not IS_EMPTY"

    limit="30"}
```

Can it be done?
Does someone has a suggestion? Custom query?

Comment: Is there a reason you're not storing all your videos in a dedicated channel and using relationships/categories to associate them with other channel entries?? That would generally be the best way.

Answer (score 1):

In the end it seemed that this is not possible in any current way.
So I tried it with Low Search (no luck) and contacted Low via his GetSatisfaction support board.
For a fee, he made a special filter for Low Search that would apply the search parameter fields only tho the channels containing them, in order to accomplish my goal.
Now it works like a dream.

The code I now use is:

```
{exp:low_search:results 
    channel='articles|instagram'
    disable="categories|category_fields|member_data|pagination"
    status="not closed" 
    dynamic="off" 
    limit="50" 
    collection="articles|instagram"
    orderby="date"
    sort="desc"

    smart_field_search="yes"
    search:article_videos="not IS_EMPTY"
    search:instagram_video_url="not IS_EMPTY"
}
    {if channel_short_name == 'instagram'}
        <!-- CODE -->
    {if:elseif channel_short_name == 'articles'}
        <!-- CODE -->
    {/if}
{/exp:low_search:results}
```

He might release it is some future version.

Comment: This is implemented in Low Search v3.3.3.